# Needing to Include Missing Values in list append

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am looking to create a dataframe of URLs and Marketo Form Ids (if they are on the page at all). The problem I am having is that when I come across a page that does not have a form, the missing value is not appended to the blank list. This is messing up my end result of identifying which URLs have which form ID on them.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

# pages to scrape for code
url_list = pd.read_csv("/Users/derekgunn/Documents/Clients/Achievers Site Map 2-23-22/test.csv")

# turn urls into list
urls = list(url_list['URLs'])

# empty lists for dataframe
id_list = []

# loop to scrape URLs
for loop in urls:
    # get list of URLs
    get = requests.get(loop)
    # turn get variable into html format
    response = get.text
    # parses response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

    for id in soup.find_all("form"):
        if id is None:
            id_list.append("No Form Found")
        else:
            id_list.append(id.get("id"))
print(id_list)
```

URLs I have been using to test (I have 35 but apparently I can only post 8??):

https://www.achievers.com/privacy-policy-archived/ 
https://www.achievers.com/news/ 
https://www.achievers.com/awn-book-club/ 
https://www.achievers.com/tofv2/ 
https://www.achievers.com/the-future-of-employee-experience/ 
https://www.achievers.com/referral/demo-18-06-2021/ 
https://www.achievers.com/request-a-demo/ 
https://www.achievers.com/demo-2021-06-18/

Comment: 1) Logic - look at this bit closely `for id in soup.find_all("form"): ....... if id is None:`  2) Avoid using `id` as a variable name as it is an inbuilt function name.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a sample row from your CSV file to allow us to test it

Comment: @MartinEvans I have added some of the URLs, i'm not allowed to post all of them due to the "new account" restriction".

Comment: @QHarr should I try using the soup.find_all("form") instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to first test if there are any forms before iterating over them. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

# pages to scrape for code
url_list = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

# turn urls into list
urls = list(url_list['URLs'])

# empty lists for dataframe
id_list = []

# loop to scrape URLs
for url in urls:
    get = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get.content, 'html.parser')

    forms = soup.find_all("form")

    if forms:
        for form in forms:
            id_list.append([url, form.get("id")])
    else:
        id_list.append([url, "No Form Found"])
        
for url, form_id in id_list:
    print(f"{form_id:15} {url}")
```

This approach shows which URLs found a suitable form:

```
No Form Found   https://www.achievers.com/privacy-policy-archived/
No Form Found   https://www.achievers.com/news/
No Form Found   https://www.achievers.com/awn-book-club/
No Form Found   https://www.achievers.com/tofv2/
mktoForm_2460   https://www.achievers.com/the-future-of-employee-experience/
mktoForm_738    https://www.achievers.com/referral/demo-18-06-2021/
No Form Found   https://www.achievers.com/request-a-demo/
mktoForm_738    https://www.achievers.com/demo-2021-06-18/
```

Comment: This is awesome!! Thank you!

I have not seen that final print statement before. Can you help me understand how it works? Sorry for the basic question. Two months into python ans still learning a ton obviously

Comment: They are called `f` strings. They allow variables (actually any expression) to be included inside the string to make formatting clearer and easier. Take a look at [Fancier output formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)